# AWS EB docker app: why to configure nginx twice?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a single docker container application on AWS Elasticbeanstalk. When I first time faced the problem *Too large file* I managed that with additional nginx-configuration `client_max_body_size 500M;`. But now I relaunch an instance on AWS, updated the instance software from the AWS Console and my application prompts `413 Request Entity Too Large` again.

I tested docker-container on a local machine -- everything is fine. When I change `client_max_body_size` -- it works like supposed to. But when I deploy to AWS EB -- it promts an error.

I noticed that on local machine I had a response from **nginx/1.4.3 (Ubuntu)**. And from AWS I have a response from **nginx/1.8.0** compiled with gcc RedHat.

- Could it be the problem with AWS EC2 nginx configuration?
- How does a request pass through the system to the app on AWS EB? AWS EC2 with nginx/1.8 handles a request and redirects it to Docker app where nginx/1.4.3 processes it again? So I need to setup `client_max_body_size` twice?

---

That's the *Dockerfile* of the app:

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN echo "exit 0" > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev python-dev
RUN apt-get install -y python-setuptools
RUN apt-get install -y python-virtualenv nginx gunicorn supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y rabbitmq-server
RUN easy_install pip

RUN mkdir -p /deploy/app
ADD requirements.txt /deploy/app/
RUN pip install -r /deploy/app/requirements.txt

COPY . /deploy/app

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY flask.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/flask.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask.conf
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY upload_limit.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/upload_limit.conf

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY gunicorn.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/gunicorn.conf

COPY rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config

EXPOSE 80 5000

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

*upload_limit.conf*:

```
client_max_body_size 500M;
```

---

#### UPDATE

Now I have to configure nginx twice:

1. In the docker container
2. Manually on AWS EC2

After that it works. But I still wonder *what is the 'right way' of deploying an app to AWS without manual configuration of AWS EC2 instances*?

Comment: How did you "manually" configure the setting on AWS EC2? Is there an Elastic Beanstalk setting in the UI or alterable via .ebextensions? Did you have to SSH in to the EC2 instances themselves? Or something else?

Comment: I did it with SSH on EC2 adding `client_max_body_size 500m;` to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. The same I have for a Docker container. The same I do for EC2 nginx also. So I do it twice and not sure it's *the right way*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk (EB) appears to install its own Nginx on each EC2 instance it provisions, which accepts requests first and then passes them into the deployed Docker container.

Therefore if your Docker container has its own Nginx, it's only receiving connections after the EB Nginx gets the request first.

To automatically configure the EB Nginx to increase the max request body size, add the following file to your ZIP file with your Dockerfile:

**.ebextensions/nginx.config**:

```
files:
    '/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf':
        mode: '000755'
        owner: root
        group: root
        # Enable large uploads.
        content: |
            client_max_body_size 500M;
```

Comment: there’s some conflicting info saying it should be inside an `http { }` section—is one right? http://quabr.com/28030736/how-to-resolve-error-413-request-entity-too-large-in-nginx-and-amazon-elasticbea